# Copy constructing from a derived object

Tags: c++

In the following code, the function foo is copy constructing a Base object c from a Derived object d. My question is: are we getting an exact copy? Because I'm not getting the polymorphic behavior I'm expecting

```
#include<iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void sayHello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello Base" << std::endl ;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void sayHello() override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello Derived" << std::endl ;
    }
};

void foo(Base* d)
{

    Base* c = new Base(*d);
    c->sayHello() ;
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    foo(&d) ;  //outputs Hello Base
}
```

Comment: `new Base` makes a `Base`

Comment: You need `virtual  Base* clone() const;` in `Base`.

Comment: You don't need a clone() method in this case, the compiler will always try to create a copy constructor. So what you get here is an exact copy of the base class, That's why you see as output "Hello Base"

Comment: I'm wondering is the vptr that points to a vTable is copied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected polymorphic behavior will come into existence when the `Base` class pointer points to `Derived` class object. Then at run time the actual type of object pointed to by the `Base` class pointer will be checked and appropriate function will get called.

`Base* c = new Base(*d);  // <<-- case of object slicing`

Here, `c` points to `Base` class object. Therefore, `c->sayHello() ;` is bound to call the `Base::sayHello()` at runtime.

`are we getting an exact copy?`. No since you are creating a `Base` object due to `new Base`. Due to object slicing the `Base` part of the `*d` object is passed to `copy c'tor` and what you get is corresponding `Base` object.

`Base *c = new Derived(*d);` will give the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `virtual` constructor nor copy constructor.

However, it is possible to define a function that behaves like one.

In my case, it is the `virtual` member function `copy()` which I added to OP's sample:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* copy() const { return new Base(*this); }

    virtual void sayHello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello Base" << std::endl ;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* copy() const override { return new Derived(*this); }

    void sayHello() override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello Derived" << std::endl ;
    }
};

void foo(Base* d)
{

    Base* c = d->copy();
    c->sayHello() ;
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    foo(&d) ;  //outputs Hello Derived
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello Derived
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b4e11845cfbec9c)</kbd>

The drawback is that every derived class of `Base` has to provide it to make it function properly. (I've no idea how to convince the compiler to check this for me with any trick.)

A partial solution could be to make `copy()` pure virtual in the `class Base` (assuming it is not meant to be instantiable).

Comment: You can make `copy()` a pure `virtual` function to force derived classes to implement it.

Comment: @RSahu That's correct for abstract base classes, you're right. However, it still doesn't help for e.g. `class DerivedDerived: public Derived`. Unfortunately, in my professional projects it occurs that I want to have `Derived` instancable as well.

Comment: @RSahu However, worth to note - I edited your hint in.

Comment: It happens some times. My experience is that when it happens, it is best to make `Derived` to be uninstantiable class.

Comment: @RSahu :-) E.g. a scene graph group (should be instantiable) but any specialized group (transformation, switch, level-of-detail, or whatever) as well. I could insert an abstract base class but for now I decided to be carefully. (It's easy to recognize when a certain class can never be copied and the virtual copy method would be the first I would check in this case...)

Comment: Here's something that might be worthwhile. http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/020163371x/items/item33.html. Also, Scott Meyers offers some justification for making non-leaf classes abstract classes in [Effective C++](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876/ref=asc_df_0321334876/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312060980065&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14784779605848658344&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9030458&hvtargid=pla-522244111150&psc=1).

Comment: I guess the default copy ctor is not copying the vptr and the vTable and hence we have to have a  clone function in every derived class and use it instead of the copy ctor

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar As I wrote initially: A copy constructor cannot be `virtual`. You name the constructor to call by it's (class) identifier. The argument type isn't considered for that.

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar The vTable is not the only issue. Prior to construction/copying, there has to happen the allocation of proper memory inside of `new`. Although, there should be the size of the instance to copy somewhere in the heap management, a class itself has no runtime size reflection I know about. (`sizeof` is always evaluated at compile-time. It had to be implemented by another virtual method if required.) Btw. instance to copy doesn't need to be stored in heap. Hence, allocation of memory with proper size for resulting instance would be an issue as well.

Comment: @Scheff Obviously right memory allocation is an issue, so the compiler allocates memory to fit the base class. What I'm not getting is why not copying the right references to functions

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar _What I'm not getting is why not copying the right references to functions_ That would be terrible. It would make your instance a "Frankenstein monster" - an instance of `Base` with `virtual`methods of `Derived`. Consider, that these virtual methods may access members of `Derived` which may not exist in that instance of `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

you may wonna change the line of new

```
Base* c = new Derived(*d);
```

so you have the type Derived in a Base pointer. During runtime it is looked up, which type it is and you get the right output.

let me know if im wrong... just created this out of my mind on the fly.

Comment: I don't want the foo function to be aware of any derived class

Comment: whether you want it or not... in some kind, foo has to know. the compiler or in this case the RTTI cant guess what you want. it has to know the type in some way.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about whether or not this is copy constructing lets add some members. `Base` will have a member, `m_b` and `Derived` will inherit `m_b` but also have another member `m_d`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    const int m_b;
    Base() = delete;
    Base(const int a_b) : m_b(a_b) {}
    virtual void sayHello() {
        std::cout << "Base " << m_b << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    const int m_d;
    Derived() = delete;
    Derived(const int a_b, const int a_d) : Base(a_b), m_d(a_d) {}
    void sayHello() override {
        std::cout << "Derived " << m_b << ' ' << m_d << std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(Derived* a) {
    Base* b = new Base(*a);
    b->sayHello(); // Output is "Base 1", 1 was copied from argument a
}

void bar(Derived* a) {
    Base* d = new Derived(*a);
    d->sayHello(); // Output is "Derived 1 2"
}

int main() {
    Derived d(1, 2);
    foo(&d);
    bar(&d);
    return 0;
}
```

The line:

```
Base* b = new Base(*a);
```

Created a `Base` and so `sayHello` calls `Base`'s implementation which doesn't know about `m_d`. However this line does copy `m_b` from the derived class

The line:

```
Base* d = new Derived(*a);
```

Created a `Derived` and so `sayHello` calls `Derived`'s implementation which copied both `m_b` and `m_d`